# Maven - Running mvn without arguments

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-profiles

Does running mvn with no arguments in the directory of the project result in the default lifecylce being executed for that project?

What if a profile is specified with the -P flag? does it execute the default lifecycle and binds any plugins in the profile to the phases they declare?

Comment: By default it will start to scan the project and will fail with: `No goals have been specified for this build.You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal...`.

Comment: What if it doesn't fail? That's actually the case with a hippoCMS tutorial project. It's getting built instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your pom you can use the tag **defaultGoal** to specify the goal that should be executed by maven if you do not specify nothing on the command line.
See [POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html)